# Importing xml file to datagridview using linq to XML. data not displaying correctly

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

My XML file...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files>
        <file type="main">
<document>Report.pdf</document>
         <field name="Company">Northwind</field>
         <field name="Description">monthly report</field>
         <line>
               <field name="Description">Error</field>
               <field name="Type">4444</field>
         </line>
         <line>
               <field name="Description">Info</field>
               <field name="Type">4562</field>
         </line>
         <line>
               <field name="Description">Error</field>
               <field name="Type">2135</field>
         </line>
          <field name="Analyst">Bob</field>
          <field name="Manager">Steve</field>
          <field name="Dept">Finance</field>
          </file>
</files>
```

My Code as it stands...

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\xmltest\input.xml");

                var lines = from item in xdoc.Descendants("line")

                            select new
                            {
                                Description = item.Value,
                                Type = item.Value

                            };

                dataGridView1.DataSource = lines.ToArray();
```

These is the results I get...

[image]

The results I would like are...

[image]

The Code I thought might work...

```
 XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(@"C:\xmltest\input.xml");

                var lines = from item in xdoc.Descendants("line")

                            select new
                            {
                                Description = item.Attribute("field").Value,
                                Type = item.Value

                            };

                dataGridView1.DataSource = lines.ToArray();
```

The Error I receive is...

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is:-

```
item.Attribute("field").Value  //this line
```

Just see your first query, it is returning that result because `item` represents each `line` node with it's respective `field` node present inside it. Say for instance for the first `item` will be:-

```
<line>
  <field name="Description">Error</field>
  <field name="Type">4444</field>
</line>
```

and so on...

Now, in your second query when you say, `item.Attribute("field").Value` it will throw `Null reference exception` because each `item` does not contain an attribute `field` (as you can see above) rather it is an `element`. So you should write `item.Element("field")` instead. But, still that will not give you the expected result because you want to fetch data based on attribute value `Description` and `name`. You can write your query like this:-

```
var lines = from item in xdoc.Descendants("line")
            let fields = item.Elements("field")
            select new
                {
                   Description = (string)fields
                       .FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Attribute("name") == "Description"),
                   Type = (string)fields
                       .FirstOrDefault(n => (string)n.Attribute("name") == "Type"),
                };
```

**Explanation:**

`xdoc.Descendants("line")` will fetch all the line nodes as demonstrated above, now inside this we need to find all the `fields` node so we store that in a variable called `fields`. Finally while projecting I have used `FirstOrDefault` method to fetch the first matching `name` attribute whose value is either `Description` or `Type` and fetch it's value.

Comment: Thanks works great and i understand what's going on now :).

Answer (score 1):

You can try filtering by attribute like this:

```
XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");

var lines = from item in xdoc.Descendants("line")
            select new
            {
                Description = item.Elements("field").Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "Description").First().Value,
                Type = item.Elements("field").Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("name") == "Type").First().Value
            };

var array = lines.ToArray();

foreach (var item in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Description}\t{item.Type}");
}
```

It would yield the following results:

```
Error   4444
Info    4562
Error   2135
```

Answer (score 1):

How about DataSet?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(FILENAME);

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[1];
        }
    }
}
​
```